# how to obtain a "request token" in callback servlet?

Tags: java, oauth, linkedin-api, scribe

I posted this question already to [scribe-java github](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/issues/255). I wonder, where I can get `Token` object inside my callback servlet, if I only have a `String` from LinkedIn server. This is how Scribe wants me to retrieve an "access token":

```
OAuthService#getAccessToken(token, verifier);
```

I can't instantiate `token` from a `String`, since its constructor requires also a `secret`. Can somebody explain what do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Long story](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/issues/255) short, you should keep the `Token` object between requests, or at least the two strings that conform it and recreate like this:

`Token t = new Token(token, secret);`